# Selecting a single record from the same multiple rows from a single table

Tags: sql

I have a table,

```
+-----+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| ID  |  companyName   |  companyAddress | brandId |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| 1   |  Mian and sons |   154 C         |    1    |
| 2   |  Mian and sons |   154 C         |    2    |
| 3   |  Mian and sons |   154 C         |    3    |
+-----+----------------+-----------------+---------+
```

**Query**

```
select companyName from Company;
```

And I get only one of three, for example

```
+---------------+
| companyName   |
+---------------+
| Mian and sons |
+---------------+
```

Comment: if your question is how to get:   

  `select distinct companyName   from yourtable`

Comment: You can use group by 'select companyName, companyAddress     from Company GROUP BY companyName, companyAddress'

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of `distinct` or `group by`

```
select distinct companyName from table t
```

`Group by` seems more efficient over `distinct`

```
select companyName
from table t
group by companyName
```

Comment: _Group by seems more efficient over distinct_? May be true for some dbms - which one? - but not in general. (And no dbms is specified here.)

Comment: On any modern DBMS `group by` will not be more (or less) efficient than `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by`

```
select companyName from Company group by companyName
```

Comment: Why complicate things... To get distinct rows, simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he is trying to say is that, he wants to print all the company names that are in the companyName column. What I think is the query will return one company name as all the company names in the column are the same " Mian and sons". If there were some different company names in the companyName column like "Jason and brothers" it would print them too, like:

```
+--------------------+
| companyName        |
+--------------------+
| Mian and sons      |
+--------------------+
| Jason and brothers |
+--------------------+
```

So, my advice is, try to add some other name in the companyName column and check it.